# Remote Desktop on multiple ports

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdc

Can you adivse how to enable the Remote Desktop/Terminal services service to listen on two different ports at the same time?

ie.  I wish to connect using either port 3388 or 3389

This is on a windows 2003 server

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do so by adding a new registry key listing your new port, by following these steps:

- Run REGEDIT
- Export the following key:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp
- Edit the REG file and change the name of the key to something like:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp-New
- In the REG file find
  PortNumber
  and change it to whatever port you want.
- Import the REG file back to the registry.

> Source:http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=555031

Comment: You can also just create a new listener through the Host Session Manager MMC

Comment: @PnP - Do you know if the Host Session Manager MMC available for a Windows 7 machine?